# asp.net-core save float as int

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm working on this application in asp.net core 6.0 where I'm trying to save a float value (in this case 0.4) and it's being saved as an int with a value of 4. I don't understand why the class has a value of 4, but when checking the model state, the value of the "water" variable is 0.4 (the correct one).
Here we have the class:[Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c3mf.jpg)

```
public class RPGH01_01
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   [Display(Name="Toma agua*")]
   public float Water { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Valor cloro**")]
   public float Chlorine { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Color")]
   public bool Color { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Olor")]
   public bool Smell { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Turbidez")]
   public bool Turbidity { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Sabor")]
   public bool Flavor { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Observaciones")]
   public string Observations { get; set; }
   public int UserID { get; set; }

}
```

Values of the class:[Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iHGL.png)
and value of the input and the model state validation:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Water,Date,Chlorine,Color,Smell,Turbidity,Flavor,Observations,UserID")] RPGH01_01 rPGH01_01)
{
   //This is to know what user create the report
   var userAccountId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("user");
   rPGH01_01.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(userAccountId);

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     _context.Add(rPGH01_01);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
   }
   return View(rPGH01_01);
}
```

[modelstate validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33FZI.png)
Thanks for your time

I have tried inserting other values (such as 0.4), but it rejects them because they are text. I have changed the variables to see if it worked by using double instead of float.

Comment: ALWAYS include your source as _text_ (formatted as `code`), not as a picture. To what are you _saving_ this value.  Take a look in the [help] about [ask] a question

Comment: Why is `rPGH01_01` being passed into the `Create` method with a value of 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to your configured culture.

In the United States, a period is used as a decimal marker while commas are used as separators. But those separators are largely ignored

```
float.Parse("4,500", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")); // 4500
float.Parse("4,5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));   // 45
float.Parse("0,4", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));   // 4
```

In Chile, the comma is used as a decimal marker and the period is used as a separator.

```
float.Parse("0.4", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-CL"))    // 4
float.Parse("0,4", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-CL"))    // 0.4
```

This may not be a bug: if your intended audience comes from a culture that represents numbers this way, users might actually expect to enter `"0,4"` instead to represent `0.4`.

If you have users from a variety of cultures, you'll need to find a way to determine the user's expected culture and [set it on the request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0).